# How to modify a file but only one occurrence using ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

I am using ansible, currently trying replace but open to lineinfile modules.  But I want to edit only the last column in the row that starts with root (the first occurrence of 0).  https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html I have been looking at the documentation and cannot edit only the first occurrence. What am I missing?

foo.txt as follows then the ansible code below the contents of the file.

```
/root/bar/foo /                           defaults        1 0
/foo/bar/foo /                           defaults        1 0
/foo/bar/foo /                           defaults        1 0
/foo/bar/foo /                           defaults        1 0
/foo/bar/foo /                           defaults        1 0



- name: edit
  replace:
   path: /path/to/foo.txt
   regexp: '0+$'
   replace: '1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *"Edit only the last column in the row that starts with root."*

A: The *regexp* and *replace* below do the job

```
    regexp: '^/root/(.*) 0+$'
    replace: '/root/\1 1'
```

Comment: works! locate with root the replace that line.  I thought there may be a literal regex that would satisfy that.